# SQL WHERE if field is serialized

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I've got a problem which needs to be solved... 
I have table where one of the fields is serialized (field: s_field). 
It's just an array of id's. 
But now I need to get all data entries WHERE s_field = 5.. 
So I have entries where s_field is `serialized(array(4, 5, 6));` and there are tons of these entries... so how do I get - using sql - all entries where one of the s_field id's are id == 5;

Hope you understand what I mean

And I don't think that getting all entries and each of them unserialize and check is not the best thing to do, because there are LOTS of them

Comment: Can you change the existing functionality? You would be much better storing those values in a separate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the `zerofill` attribute to the ID field so you will have, say, `0000005` rather than `5`, then using `LIKE` to match the for `0000005`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your entry really looks like `serialized(array(4, 5, 6));` you could find a '5' with this query:

a:3:{i:0;i:4;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:6;}

```
SELECT some_field WHERE s_field LIKE '%, 5,%'
```

However the better solution would be to unserialize all that data and put it in relational tables.

**EDIT:**
As @kyra pointed, this won't work for the first and last item of the array.

So if you get no result with the first query you could then try:

```
SELECT some_field WHERE s_field LIKE '%(5,%'
```

And then finally:

```
SELECT some_field WHERE s_field LIKE '%, 5)%'
```

If you have mostly fields with only one element you should start with the second query.

**EDIT:**

Of course if the serialized data actually looks like this: `a:3:{i:0;i:4;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:6;}` you can locate the '5' like this:

```
SELECT some_field WHERE s_field LIKE '%i:5;%'
```

And this way it should work even for the fisrt and last items.

Comment: Also the `serialized` version of `array(4, 5, 6)` is `a:3:{i:0;i:4;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:6;}%`

Comment: That's not what the OP said, I think he showed us what actually is in his table.

Comment: Oh, I see. Why would he do that though? =]

Comment: ... as Kyra said in my table is serialized version of array.. so my table field looks like a:3:{i:0;i:4;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:6;}

Comment: Right, then probably the `zerofill` attribute will solve your problem, although if you're dealing with existing data is not very feasible.